# take average value resample raster

Tags: python, raster, resampling

I have one population raster with a coarse resolution as 100m, i want to resample it to a finer resolution, 75m.
I already have one population data in raster where each pixel value is the number of people, numbers of people within each 100m*100m. When I need to resample it to 75m, the new pixel range (min_r_x, max_r_x, min_r_y, max_r_y) may across several pixels of the 100m raster(here i use four parts, red, blue, green and yellow as an example). my idea is, first get the location of four vertexs of each pixel in this desired 75m raster, then take the population value that vertexs is in, and calculate the area percentage to generate the resample result value.
You can refer to the picture below as a simple illustration.

```
Original_R = 100 
 R = 75 
 Area_red = (max_x - min_r_x)*(max_r_y-min_y)
 Area_blue = (R – (max_x –min_r_x))*(max_r_y-min_y)
 Area_green = (max_x - min_r_x)*(R – (max_r_y-min_y))
 Area_yellow = (R – (max_x –min_r_x))*(R – (max_r_y-min_y))
 Value_resample = (10 *area_red     +20*area_blue+40*area_green+50*area_yellow)/(original_R* original_R)
```

I tried with resample a raster with 1 row, 2 columns in 4 m resolution to a new raster with 2 m resolution.

```py
pop = (((0,4,0,4),10),((4,8,4,8),30))#original raster with two pixels, store as the Vertex coordinates ((xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax),pixel value)
min_r_x = [] 
min_r_y = []
max_r_x = []
max_r_y = []
pop_r = []
x1 = []
x2 = []
y1 = []
y2 = []
#loc = []
pop_r = []
area = 4*4
#re = 4
newre = 2
#max_y = 4
#min_x = 0
val = []
#get the vertex coordinates of new raster
for row in range(2):
    for col in range(4):
        min_r_x = 0 + col*newre
        max_r_x = 0 + (col+1)*newre
        max_r_y = 4 + row*(-newre)
        min_r_y = 4 + (row+1)*(-newre)
        pop_r.append(((min_r_x,max_r_x,max_r_y,min_r_y),0))

        #take each of the new raster vertex cooordinates locate their position
        for i in range(len(pop_r)):
            pairs = pop_r[i]
            coor = pairs[0]
            #val = pairs[1]              
            coorxmin = coor[0]
            coorxmax = coor[1]
            coorymax = coor[2]
            coorymin = coor[3]#loop each vertex of pixels            
            for j in range(len(pop)):
                record = pop[j]
                loc = record[0]
                xmin = loc[0]
                xmax = loc[1]
                ymin = loc[2]
                ymax = loc[3]
        #here is the place that I have some problem, it seems not right
                if xmin <= coorxmin <= xmax:                
                   x1.append(xmax-coorxmin)
                   val.append(record[1])
                if xmin <= coorxmax <= xmax: 
                   x2.append(xmax - coorxmax)                 
                   val.append(record[1])
                if ymin <= coorymin <= ymax:
                   y1.append(ymax-coorymin)
                   val.append(record[1])
                if ymin <= coorymax <= ymax:
                   y2.append(ymax-coorymax)
                   val.append(record[1])
                value = (x1 * y1 * val + x1*y2*val + x2*y1*val + x2*y2*val)/area
       pop_r.append(((min_r_x[i],max_r_x[i],min_r_y[i],max_r_y[i]),value))
```

Comment: Could you expand on some of the underlying subject matter assumptions? What is a population raster? What is `m` in `100 m`? What is a vertex in this context? How would it be possible to get a finer resolution from a more coarse resolution? In your example code, why is there only two datapoints? What is `min_r_x` vs `max_r_x`? In each datapoint there is a `10` and `30`, what are those? What I think I'm saying is that is that you need to express your problem somewhat more, even though it seems you have a MCVE-question, it is hard to help when we don't know the assumptions of your field of work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I should explain it more clear.